# Plural or singular in many nouns expression

Tags: grammatical-number

What is gramatically correct to say:

> a specific type of solutions introduces
>   or
>
> a specific type of solutions introduce

Comment: This is one that a lot of people get snarled up in. Please could you amend your question to turn your phrases into complete sentences? Usually full context makes it easier for us to answer. Thanks.

Comment: Both are possible depending on what is meant. If the reference is to the set of solutions of the specific type, then it's singular. OTOH, if the reference is to the solutions of the type, then it's plural.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the meaning of the whole sentence. However, it can be determined based on the following criteria (as a general rule of thumb):

"a specific type of solutions introduces" - Correct, if this *type* consists of solutions, which are all similar and neither one of them (individually) "introduces"(sth.). Thus the agreement of the *verb* goes with "type", 3rd person singular.

"a specific type of solutions introduce" - Correct, if this *type* consists of a set of solutions, but each one of them is unique and can individually "introduce" (sth.). Here the verb agrees with "solutions".